# Romantic as a noun or an adjective?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, adjectives, nouns

In the movie Casablanca, Renault tells Rick (@ 16'45"):

**"I like to think that you killed a man. It's the romantic in me."**

I can't find this phrase in the dictionary: " it's (...) in me". But I think "romantic" should be a noun here and by way of analogy, it should be OK to place any noun there. Like I should be able to say "It's the 'rational' in me" ?

Am I correct?!

Comment: You’re correct that you could put a different noun there. But “rational” is an adjective.

Comment: Thank you! then "Rationale" with an 'e' at the end should work.

Comment: That doesn’t work either, because a person can’t be a rationale, and the noun that you place there has to be something that a person can be. You could use “rationalist”, though

Comment: “romantic” here is a noun meaning “romantic person”, which is why it works in this idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand that "romantic" can be both an adjective (eg "*he is romantic*") and a noun (eg "*he is **a** romantic*").

The expression "the [noun] in me" is quite common and can actually work with either an adjective *or* a noun!

With an adjective, the expression is quite literal. For example, someone of mixed heritage might say credit a particular character trait to one part of their heritage by saying "that's the Latin in me" (*Latin* being an adjective to describe anything relating to Latin countries).

With a *noun*, it is a more figurative expression - by saying, for example "that's the *Latino* in me", (a Latino being a person of Latin American origin or descent) a person is speaking as if there is a whole Latin person within them, as well as perhaps other figurative persons that represent other aspects of their heritage or personality.

In your example, "romantic" seems to be a **noun** - it is figuratively saying that a romantic person exists within them, as part of their personality.